# Python Multiple Calculation in Pivot Table

Tags: python

I am looking to make a Pivot Table with multiple calculations. Take for example my table initially looks like this.

```
+---------+----------+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
| Region  | Country  | Vol_Sales| Weight  | Acquisition| Processing|
+---------+----------+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
| Asia    | Japan    |  400     |  6      | Auto       | Manual    |        
+---------+----------+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
| Asia    | Singapore|  700     |  7      | Auto       | Auto      |
+---------+----------+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
| Europe  | UK       |  600     |  8      | Manual     | Auto      |
+---------+----------+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
| .       | .        |          |         |            |           |
+---------+----------+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
| .       | .        |          |         |            |           |
+---------+----------+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
| .       | .        |          |         |            |           |
+---------+----------+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
| Africa  | Egypt    | 700      |  7      | Auto       | Auto      |
+---------+----------+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
```

I want the result of the pivot to look like this.

```
+---------+----------+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
|Region   |Tot_Sales |Acq_Prop  |Proc_Prop|Avg_Weight  |           |
+---------+----------+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
| Asia    | 80,000   | 80.6     | 70.2    | 7.2        |           |
+---------+----------+----------+---------+------------+-----------+

Total_Sales = Sum of Vol_Sales
Acq_Prop = Acquisition(Auto) / Total(Auto+Manual) * 100
Proc_Prop = Processing(Auto) / Total(Auto+Manual) * 100
Avg_Weights = Average of Weight group by Region
```

So far what I did was

```
Sales_Report = Sales_Report.assign(counter = 1)
Report = pd.pivot_table(Sales_Report, index = ['REGION'], columns = ['Acquisition', 'Processing'],  values = ['counter'], aggfunc = 'sum', fill_value = 0, margins = True, margins_name = 'Total')
```

Then I re-arrange the table

```
create a list of the new column names in the right order
new_cols=[('{1} {2}'.format(*tup)) for tup in Table.columns]

assign it to the Table
Report.columns = new_cols

resort the index, so you get the columns in the order you specified
Report.sort_index(axis='columns')
```

Finally to get the calculated Columns

```
Report['Acq_Prop'] = round((Report['Auto Auto'] + Report['Auto Manual']) / (Report['Auto Auto'] + Report['Auto Manual'] + Report['Manual Auto'] + Report['Manual Manual'])* 100, 2)
Report['Proc_Prop'] = round((Report['Auto Auto'] + Report['Manual Auto']) / (Report['Auto Auto'] + Report['Auto Manual'] + Report['Manual Auto'] + Report['Manual Manual'])* 100, 2)
```

I am struggling to add Tot_Sales and Avg_Weights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

Define your aggregation operations for each column

```
volFunc = np.sum
acFunc = lambda x: (x.value_counts()['auto']/x.shape[0])*100
procFunc = lambda x:(x.value_counts()['auto']/x.shape[0])*100
weightFunc = np.mean
```

Pass aggregation operations as a dictionary to each respective column

```
df.pivot_table(
    index='region',
    aggfunc={'Vol_Sales':volFunc,
             'Weight':weightFunc,
             'Acquisition':acFunc,
             'Processing':procFunc}
)
```

Toy example I made up:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'region':['asia','asia','europe','asia','asia','asia'],
                  'Weight':np.random.randint(5,10,6),
                  'Vol_Sales':np.random.randint(100,800,6),
                  'Acquisition':['man','man','auto','auto','auto','auto'],
                  'Processing':['man','man','auto','auto','auto','man']
                 })
```

output from toy example:

```
    Acquisition Processing  Vol_Sales   Weight
region              
asia    60.0    40.0        2269        6.6
europe  100.0   100.0       268         7.0
```

Rename and rearrange resulting columns as needed

Comment: I wonder why when I pass the Aggregation operation, it returns me with KeyError: 'Auto'

My Table data has 'Auto' and 'Manual' as input, and i input just as that. Vol and Weight works just fine, just that for Acq and Proc give me that KeyError:'Auto'

Comment: `acFunc = lambda x: (x.value_counts()['auto']/x.shape[0])*100` see how I'm calling `'auto'` in this aggregation function, if your input is called `'Auto'` you need to capitalize otherwise the key will not exist

Comment: Yeah, I capitalized it with 'Auto' instead of 'auto' since my input is Auto.
```Total_Func = np.sum
Acq_Func = lambda x: (x.value_counts()['Auto']/x.shape[0])*100
Proc_Func = lambda x: (x.value_counts()['Auto']/x.shape[0])*100
Weight_Func = np.mean```
I wrote this and what I got was KeyError when I ran

Comment: ```Table = pd.pivot_table(Filtered_Subs, index = ['REGION','SOURCE_CODE'], aggfunc ={'RETRIEVAL_METHOD':Acq_Func,'PROCESS_METHOD':Proc_Func,'Weights':Weight_Func})```

That's what I added

Comment: Hmm it may be that your values aren't in the form of neat strings. Take your `Acquisition` column and run `.value_counts()` on it, and see what indices you get. Each indices should be a unique value that appears in your column and the number of times each unique value appears. The one closest to `auto` should be the one you want as a key

Comment: Auto      14232
Manual     2693
Name: RETRIEVAL_METHOD, dtype: int64

That's the return, *Acquisition = RETRIEVAL_METHOD in my original file. It might have something to do with TypeError because it says String object can not be interpreted it as an integer but I am still not sure where it went wrong

Comment: `df['Acquisition'].value_counts().index`, check if it's a string. If not you may need to customize a way to key the resulting series of `value_counts()`.

Comment: Index(['Auto', 'Manual'], dtype='object') that's the result

Comment: `acFunc = lambda x: (x.value_counts()['Auto']/x.shape[0])*100` Should work then, can't tell from my end since I dont know what your environment is like :/ Maybe try `acFunc = lambda x: (x.value_counts().loc['Auto']/x.shape[0])*100`, if that doesn't work then you'll have to check that your versions are all up to date and if you're using a notebook make sure you're not shadowing any previous variables.